# How can I link directly to a tab on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to load a Facebook app tab directly, rather than go through the Wall and then click to the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Tab urls are of the form:

- With vanity url

  `http://www.facebook.com/myPageName?v=app_APPLICATION_ID`

eg http://www.facebook.com/facebook?sk=app_127337483972992

- Without vanity url

  `http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Name/PAGE_ID?v=app_APPLICATION_ID`

If you click on the tab link you'll get the relevant url to the application tab on your fan page.

Comment: If you are linking from within a Facebook app, make sure to add `target="_top"`. Otherwise, it will try to load Facebook inside of a Facebook iframe.

Comment: So what is the name of the parameter? "sk" or "v"?